# How to use Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 with Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to use Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 with Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package in my NetCore app on Linux machine.

First I have configured an working Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1, it's working well.

Then on client side I installed this NuGet package: 
[image]

And write some sample code. My code working well then I'm using cloud Azure service bus in testing case, messages received/sent well and without any errors.

Next step I'm created a new SAS Authorization Rule for ServiceBus 1.1, [this way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440944.aspx) I get service bus connection string with access token. This is how it looks like:

[image]

I'm getting this error then trying to use new generated connection string:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

What shoud I do to fix it? I'm not found any suggestions, tutorials or examples in web.

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus client is designed to work with Azure Service Bus, not Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1. Also, note that the latter is no longer supported.

Comment: That's mean what there is no way to use them together? I'm scared about thougts to rewrite whole old stable apps! Did anybody really not think about back compatibility?

Comment: I have no answer for you. Not sure what backwards compatibility you're referring to when it was long time known that SBWS will be discontinued. My advise, look at Azure Service Bus if you want future for the code. As of now, SBWS is unsupported.